# document.observe("dom:loaded") not fired when window is inactive

Tags: javascript, events, dom, prototypejs

I observe this behaviour currently in Firefox 3.6.12:

When I start loading a page and then switch while it is still loading to another tab or window and come back when loading is finished, the "dom:loaded" event has not been triggered by the document observer.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in Firefox, you should report it to Mozilla. You could also try reporting it to the Prototype mailing list and they might find a solution for their next version. Both of these means waiting for a fix that might not come. But you should still report it as a bug for everyone's benefit.

You could simply move your script to the very bottom of the page, although it will run sooner than "dom:loaded" the relevant parts of the DOM should be instantiated by then.

Or you could observe the body's onLoad event, that will run later (after images are loaded) so is safer.